# resolving rails subdomain with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I have an application that comprises of a blog and a single page website ,
they are both in the same application

the blog is the root of the application, while the the single page website is just another section in the application.

```
routs.rb includes

match '/pages' => 'pages#home'
root :to => 'blogs#index'
```

the application is hosted on heroku and works perfectly: (i achieved this by hosting my app on heroku and pointing my dns to heroku i.e the heroku url is fxyear.herokuapp.com and i bought fxyear.com and pointed it to herokuapp.com and it works perfectly.

What i want to achieve is i want a subdomain to point to heroku in such a way that 
www.summit.fxyear.com will point to pages i.e match '/pages' => 'pages#home' thats all thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CNAME**

You'll have to [change the ANAME or CNAME settings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#cname-functionality-at-the-apex) for your domain, so that the `summit.fxyear.com` subdomain will point to your Rails app (Heroku app).

You can then [use constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints subdomain: "summit" do 
   get "", to: "pages#home"
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works great ... but adding a (www).summit.fxyear.com is not working but summit.fxyear.com works great